# Why add links to the response of a REST API?

Tags: rest

Why do developers add links to the response of a REST API? For example, at paginated response in this [tutorial](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest-ep2/pagination).

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=3"
        },
        "first": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user"
        },
        "prev": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=2"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=4"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://example.org/api/user?page=133"
        }
    }
    "count": 3,
    "total": 498,
    "_embedded": {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's pretty much easy to generate such link at the frontend.

Comment: It's because this way an API self describes and you only need one initial link to traverse it (without knowledge of how parameters are sent, etc.). But since it's not standard, you still need to know how the links are sent, what they mean, etc. In my opinion it's the sign of an over engineered API... Here's an explanation: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/03/rest-lesson-learned-consider-a-self-link-on-all-resources/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link!

Comment: Its called hypermedia, its REST specific style https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple opinions about this. So in my answer I'm putting on the hat of someone who *does* want to add these links. Here's a few reasons:

1. The client having less logic is kind of nice. You might have multiple clients so you don't have to reimplement the same logic.
2. It allows the server to completely change logic without having to update the client. For example, now you use `?page=x` to get to the next page, but that specific approach to paging can give you problems for certain scales / certain datasets. If you ever want to change to for example `?offset=x` the client will transparently upgrade.
3. If the `next` link doesn't exist, it also easily tells the client that there is no next page.
4. This overlaps a bit with earlier reasons, but if you are creating a API standard that multiple servers implement, you don't force the servers to implement your specific paging strategy. By using links you basically keep the door open for other implementations of your API to choose different paging strategies that are more appropriate to their infrastructure.
5. It's a 'uniform interface'. Everything in your API is a resource (including the 'next' page), which means that everything will generally behave the same. Not only pages should work like this, but also other types of relations. For instance, maybe your "user" is part of a "group". Don't specify a "groupId", specify a group link.

Lastly, you might be able to easily generate simple generic HTML interfaces for this, which might be useful for your developers. There's many HAL browsers out there.

Comment: Great answer. It should also be added that API's are not only read by machines but also by humans. It's greate Developer Experience if you can just browse an API following the links in the response to understand how it works.