# Why does REST API provide links?

Tags: rest

I'm interfacing my first REST API and I'm wondering why I need to dynamically obtain a url  in the first step befor I do the second step.

First a `GET /dms` would give me a json containing a link  `/dms/r/{repositoryid}`.

I can use this link to get a particular repository later.

In the second step I'm supposed to obtain a list of repositories with `GET /dms/r`. Which gives me a list of repositories with their ids.

**Why is the first step necessary?** Is this so they can change the urls later without affecting me?

https://portal.d-velop.de/documentation/dmsap/en/dms-api-538791722.html#DMSApp-API-UsingtheAPIfunctions

> The repository ID is determined in two steps:
>
> Determining the link relation for retrieving the list of repositories
> Retrieving the list of repositories
>
> ```
> Request
> GET /dms
> Accept: application/hal+json
> ```

> ```
> Response
> {
>   _links: {
>       repo: {
>           href: "/dms/r/{repositoryid}",
>           templated: true
>       }
>   }
> }
>
> Request
> GET /dms/r
> Accept: application/hal+json
> ```
>
> In the response, you receive an array of repositories in which the
> repository ID is listed as the id property and the repository's
> display name is listed as the name property.
>
> ```
> Response
> {
>   repositories: [
>       {
>           id: "dee1f3d3-eae8-5d9d-84d8-2d758c5ddc27",
>           name: "Contoso (A)"
>       },
>       ...
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842250/why-add-links-to-the-response-of-a-rest-api   but I'm not sure how providing a link would help in the described situation when parameter names are changed on the API side.

Comment: Yes, one of the ideas is that the URL namespace is flexible. It can live on different servers too.